# Showing a confirm button before submitting a form

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple form on my webpage. When the button is hit, the form is submitted and some data is sent to my backend. In order to handle the request and sent this data, i built a function.

Now, before the request is fired, i want to show a simple confirm panel.

Here is what i tried, the following is the function which handles the form's submission:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#settings").submit(function (event) {

      //This should be the confirm button
      $(document).ready(function() {
        swal({
            title: 'Submit your order',
            type: 'info',
            html:"Are you sure?",
            showCloseButton: false,
            showCancelButton: false,
            focusConfirm: false,
            confirmButtonText: 'Confirm',
            cancelButtonText: 'Go back',
        });
      })

      callAJAX(viewsurl,
       {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
       parameters={'settings': $('#settings').val()},

      'post',
       function(data){

       }, null, null );
  return false; 
  });
});
```

So, the data is sent when the line `callAJAX` starts. Before that, there is my panel. After the form's button is hit, the panel will be shown, the only problem is that, instead of waiting for the user to hit the Confirm button, the request is still sent, which means that my code won't stop until the panel is closed; instead, if the Confirm button is not hit, the request should not be sent. Is there any way to fix this? Is there some example to perform this task in an efficient way?

The following, instead, will work and will put the function on hold until the `OK` button is hit:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#settings").submit(function (event) {

      alert('Are you sure?');

      //Here the request is sent
      callAJAX(viewsurl,
       {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
       parameters={'settings': $('#settings').val()},

      'post',
       function(data){

       }, null, null );
  return false; 
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `$(document).ready` *inside* the submit handler?  And what is `swal()`?

Comment: You should be using [SweetAlerts callback function](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples) to decide whether or not to fire your network request. Your second example, without Sweet Alert, should be using [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) rather than `alert()`. And again, you should be checking the result to decide whether to fire your network request.

Comment: Thank you! @Turnip is there any example of callback functions? I can't seem to find it

Answer (score 0):

this can help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a confirm box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var txt;
  var r = confirm("Press a button!");
  if (r == true) {
    txt = "You pressed OK!";
  } else {
    txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for submitting an answer!  To help improve quality and ensure the usefulness of answers, can you please take some time to elaborate on yours?  What was the original problem?  What did you change?  How does that solve the problem?  You can get helpful tips on writing an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer